# oracle: get a specific date with a condition

Tags: oracle

I have this table with the information of each flight movement and the information of the origin and destination for a plane ticket for that flight.

```
   RESERVATION  FLIGHT ORIG  DEST   DT                PASSENGER_CODE PASSEN_ORI  PASSEN_DEST
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    111         LA111   MSP   LAX   01/01/2020 21:30   ABC            LAX          MIA
    111         LA111   LAX   JFK   01/01/2020 23:00   ABC            LAX          MIA
    111         LA111   JFK   MIA   02/01/2020 01:00   ABC            LAX          MIA  
    111         LA111   MIA   ATL   02/01/2020 02:00   ABC            LAX          MIA
    111         LA112   MIA   PHX   02/01/2020 03:00   ABC            MIA          ARG
    111         LA112   PHX   SCL   02/01/2020 18:45   ABC            MIA          ARG
    111         LA112   SCL   ARG   02/01/2020 23:00   ABC            MIA          ARG
    111         LA112   ARG   LIM   03/01/2020 03:00   ABC            MIA          ARG
```

i need get the info for the flight but only the date time of the departure and arrival made by the person associated with the plane ticket

```
   RESERVATION  FLIGHTS   FL_INI_ROU  FL_END_ROU PASSEN_ROUTE PASSEN_DEPARTURE_DT PASSEN_ARRIVAL_DT
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    111       LA111-LA112   MSP-ATL   MIA-LIM  LAX-ARG        01/01/2020 23:00    02/01/2020 23:00
```

I tried to get the dates for departure and arrival in 2 queries and then join them with union, but I find it inefficient.

THX!

Comment: can you please edit the question and show your query.

Answer (score 0):

Group data by reservation and flight at first, then in next step only by reservation. This way you can find all needed values:

```
select reservation, listagg(flight, '-') within group (order by mnd) flights,
       min(orig) keep (dense_rank first order by r1) || ' - ' 
         || min(dest) keep (dense_rank first order by r1) as ini_rt,
       min(orig) keep (dense_rank first order by r2) || ' - ' 
         || min(dest) keep (dense_rank first order by r2) as end_rt,
       min(o1) keep (dense_rank first order by r1) || ' - ' 
         || min(o2) keep (dense_rank first order by r2) as route,
       min(mnd) dep_dt, max(mxd) arr_dt
  from (
    select reservation, flight, 
           min(orig) keep (dense_rank first order by dt) orig, 
           min(dest) keep (dense_rank last order by dt) dest,
           row_number() over (order by min(dt)) r1, 
           row_number() over (order by min(dt) desc) r2, 
           min(passen_ori) keep (dense_rank first order by dt) o1,
           min(passen_dest) keep (dense_rank last order by dt) o2,
           min(dt) mnd, max(dt) mxd
      from flights
      group by reservation, flight )
  group by reservation
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4ea2d79df2ee92fb0422330404beff85)</sup>**